# Read SQLite database from local bundle using SharkORM

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, orm, dbaccess

I am new in iOS development and I want to read database stored in app bundle with [SharkORM](http://sharkorm.com/). I found `getCustomSettings()` delegate but I think I'm using it wrong. It creates new DB somewhere else and it is empty.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, SRKDelegate {
private static let DatabaseName : String = "data"
private static let DatabaseType : String = "db"

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    SharkORM.setDelegate(self)
    SharkORM.openDatabaseNamed("data")
    return true
}

// MARK: SharkORM

func getCustomSettings() -> SRKSettings {
    let settings = SRKSettings()
    let databaseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: AppDelegate.DatabaseName, ofType: AppDelegate.DatabaseType)!)
    settings.databaseLocation = databaseURL.deletingLastPathComponent().path
    return settings
}
}
```

My database file is named `data.db` and it is stored in `Resources/Database` folder in project.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong? Can anybody provide me working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharkORM will require R/W access to the database, the reality is that you will need to:

1) Ensure it is a SharkORM compatible database file, e.g. all the property types, names and primary keys match the object model (must have Id PK column).

2) Copy the database out of the bundle into a r/w directory on startup to use it.  R/O is possible, but harder work to achieve.

You could also use the rawExecute function to use an ATTACH command, if the tables are only to be referenced from within queries.

Comment: Can you describe how I can open the database as R/O?

Comment: Sure, you do as above.  But you make it a `class func` from memory, and you must ensure that it has absolutely zero schema changes from the model classes.  Then it should work.  The easiest way to do this is to build the DB in shark, and then put it into your bundle later on.  But this really isn't SharkORM's use scenario, i'd use something else because you are only going to bump into pain.